# Freeing lpsolve memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, linear-programming, lpsolve

I'm working on a C++ project that involves using lpsolve version 5.5 to solve many linear programs. I'm having trouble with memory leaks.

I wrote some test-code:

```
int main(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    lprec* lp = make_lp(0, 5000);    //0 rows, 5000 columns
    set_verbose(lp, IMPORTANT);
    solve(lp);
    delete(lp);
  }
}
```

This code leaks about 80 million bytes, with exactly 100 errors. Is there a known leak within lpsolve, or am I handling cleanup incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: Without a definition of ```make_lp```no one can help you! I never used lpsolve, but i highly doubt, that there are memory leaks which are observed without some hard-core usage (=low chance of memory leaks).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was a relatively simple error, caused by not reading docs carefully, but I'll leave this here in case somebody else finds it helpful.

The standard C++ `delete` will *not* free memory associated with an lprec. Use lpsolve's `delete_lp()` [(1)](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/delete_lp.htm) or `free_lp()` [(2)](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/free_lp.htm) instead.

Comment: This is a general rule! Every resource allocation function comes with its “partner” deallocation function. You will see this in **all** well-designed APIs. In fact, the lack of such an allocation/deallocation pairing would be a serious flaw in the API, even if all the deallocation function does is call `free`/`delete` (or even do nothing). This is even true across different languages, although in modern languages the deallocation is often hidden away; for instance, in a proper C++ library you’d use a destructor instead.